# Multi-threaded copying files using queue

Tags: c++, multithreading

The task:

I have many (500) `.txt` files. Each file contains other filenames. I have a filename to begin with. I need to copy that file and all files mentioned in it, and so on, to a subdirectory `copy/`. The solution must be multi-threaded.

I wrote the following code, but it executes a bit faster with one thread than with two. What's my mistake and how can I change this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
template <typename T>
class UQueue {
private:
    std::queue<T> m_queue;
    std::set<T> m_set;
public:
    bool push(const T& t) {
        if (m_set.insert(t).second) {
            m_queue.push(t);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void pop() {
        assert(!m_queue.empty());
        m_queue.pop();
    }

    const T& front() const {
        return m_queue.front();
    }

        bool empty(){
            return m_queue.empty();
        }

        int size_of_set(){
            return m_set.size();
        }           
};




template <class T>
class SafeQueue {
public:
  SafeQueue(void)
    : q()
    , m()
    , c()
  {}

  ~SafeQueue(void) {}


  void enqueue(T t) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    q.push(t);
    c.notify_one();
  }


  T dequeue(void) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    while(q.empty()) {

      c.wait(lock);
    }
    T val = q.front();
    q.pop();
    return val;
  }
  int size_of_set() {
    return q.size_of_set();
  }

  bool empty() {
    return q.empty();
  }

private:
  UQueue<T> q;
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable c;

};


void copyFile(std::string fromFile, std::string toFile){
    std::ifstream  src(fromFile, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream  dst(toFile, std::ios::binary);
    dst << src.rdbuf();
}


std::set<std::string> extract( std::string file_name ) {

    std::ifstream file(file_name) ;
    std::string line;
    std::set<std::string> temp;
    while (!file.eof()){    
        file >> line;       
        temp.insert(line);
    }
    return temp;
}


class Crawler{
    public:
        void init();
        void work();
        void thread_init();
        int processed(){return q.size_of_set();};
        Crawler(std::string start, int thr);    
        std::string target(){return m_conf.m_targetDir;};
    private:

    struct Config{
      int m_threads;
      std::string m_startFile = "1.txt";
      std::string m_targetDir = "copy"; 
    };

        Config m_conf;      
        SafeQueue<std::string> q;

};

void Crawler::init(){
    q.enqueue(m_conf.m_startFile);
}

Crawler::Crawler(std::string start, int thr){
    m_conf.m_startFile = start;
    m_conf.m_threads = thr;
}

void Crawler::work(){

    std::string path; 
    std::set<std::string> tempSet;
    while (!q.empty()){
        path = q.dequeue();


        copyFile(path, this->target() + "/" + path);
        tempSet = extract(path);

        for (auto f : tempSet){
          q.enqueue(f);
        }
    }
}

void Crawler::thread_init(){
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_conf.m_threads; ++i){
        workers.push_back(std::thread(&Crawler::work, this));   
    }
    for (auto& thr : workers){  
        thr.join();
    }
}


int main(){

    Crawler c("1.txt", 2);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    c.init();
    c.thread_init();


    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << c.processed()<< 
                    " " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end - start).count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, concurrent threaded-copying of distinct files on a non solid-state drive is nearly always going to suck in performance. There is a butterfly effect. When copying one contiguous file the heads can simply be positioned and the file subsequently scanned from end to end. When copying multiple files concurrently each block read from each file has to reposition the drive heads to the current file's read point. The result is a head armature slapping back and forth, effectively introducing all that seek time, and thereby actually *reducing* performance, not enhancing it.

Comment: There is one manufacturer that plans some next generation hard drives with dual actuators but even then it will be difficult to gain performance using 2 threads because  you will have to know where the data is stored to gain performance. [https://blog.seagate.com/craftsman-ship/multi-actuator-technology-a-new-performance-breakthrough/](https://blog.seagate.com/craftsman-ship/multi-actuator-technology-a-new-performance-breakthrough/)

Comment: @WhozCraig [Try not to use comments to answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have an accurate answer to the question, you should be posting it as an actual answer.

Comment: I think there is still a question that can be looked at if the user has a SSD. If the user has a hard drive or raid array there probably is nothing that can be done (using threads) to speed this up.

Comment: @drescherjm hysterical. the more things change the more they stay the same,Old (and I mean *old*, as in mid-70's) Burroughs drum drives had immovable heads across a single fixed arm above the drum, one head *per track*. Zero seek time, but still had rotational latency (pretty sure they had gerbils inside the drum spinning the thing while getting their exercise).

Comment: Another thing that I would point to consider is that empty() is not locked. Another thread may perform operations while calling the function resulting with inconsistency state.

Comment: Try putting the source and destination files on separate filesystems, or even better on a RAM drive based on `tmpfs` to eliminate seek times.